# Pmrep command not found - jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I am fairly new to Informatica. I am trying to automate deployment of Powercenter code from one environment to another using jenkins.

Script:

node('')

{

```
def application = 'powercenter'

stage('deploy'){



sshagent(['group']) {



        sh """ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@123.com 'cd /opt/hub/infapwc/server/bin && pmrep connect -r Repository_Service_L1 -d domain -n username -x password'"""



      }

 }
```

}

My job is failing with  error: pmrep command not found. Informatica is installed on the linux server i am doing ssh in. This works fine in putty. I am not sure what the issue is. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Your jenkins agent `$PATH` is different from your user `$PATH`, probably because your `.bashrc` changes it for you. Try using full path, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/pmrep connect`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $INFA_HOME/bin to $PATH or you can use absolute path of pmrep file.
pmrep file is available in $INFA_HOME/bin. You can check with infa admin person about path.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work; pmrep uses a couple of libraries which are located in the .../server/bin directory as well.
In order to make this work, please add the .../server/bin directory of the PowerCenter installation path (resp. ...\server\bin on Windows) to the PATH environment variable of the user ID which runs the Jenkins script before trying to invoke pmrep.